# less than and greater than symbols not working in razor template jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, c1-cms

In my razor template the jquery having a if else checking.in thet if condition the less than or greater than symbol getting some error.

here is my master lay out

```
@inherits CompositeC1WebPage
@{
    string stylesFolder = "~/Frontend/Styles";
    string jsFolder = "~/Frontend/Scripts";
    string websiteTitle = HomePageNode.Title;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<f:function name="Composite.Web.BundlingAndMinification" xmlns:f="http://www.composite.net/ns/function/1.0">
    <f:param name="Page">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="no-js" lang="@Lang">
        <head>
            <title>@CurrentPageNode.Title</title>
            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentPageNode.Description))
            {
                <meta name="description" content="@CurrentPageNode.Description" />
            }
            @PageTemplateFeature("Descriptive HTML head elements")
        </head>
        <body>


                @RenderBody()


            @RenderSection("Scripts", false);
        </body>
    </html>

</f:param>
</f:function>
```

and my home razor templte is

```
@inherits RazorPageTemplate

@functions {
    public override void Configure()
    {
        TemplateId = new Guid("a270f819-0b5c-4f7e-9194-4b554043e4ab");
        TemplateTitle = "Home_En";
        Layout = "MasterLayout.cshtml";
    }


    [Placeholder(Id = "content", Title = "Content", IsDefault = true)]
    public XhtmlDocument Content { get; set; }

    [Placeholder(Id = "aside", Title = "Aside column")]
    public XhtmlDocument Aside { get; set; }
}
@{
    string stylesFolder = "~/Frontend/Styles";
    string jsFolder = "~/Frontend/Scripts";
}
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    @*you can add template specific head elements here*@
</head>
<body id="page-top" class="index">
    <div class="ban_replace">
        <img src="/Image/test/banreplace.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>

    @Html.Raw(Content)

    @section Scripts
    {
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {

                var windowsize = $(window).width();

                if (windowsize < 480) {

                }
                else if (windowsize < 640) {

                }
                else {
                }
            });
        </script>
        <script>$(window).fadeThis();</script>
    }

</body>


</html>
```

but the console error showing uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token
can any one mhelp on this issue
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: the error in the console will point to you a line number where the error is in source? The error is not due to < symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Composite C1 requires razor function to produce valid xhtml markup, in other words to be a valid xml document. 
You can try the following constructions as a workaround:

```
<script>
  // <!--

.... your code here

  // -->
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
  // <![CDATA[

.... your code here

  // ]]>
</script>
```